# how to get vendorNo after get inserted in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm having problems with Java. I can insert data... But how can I get it? I think I did it in the wrong way. Can someone help me in how to get the `vendorNo`?

**update:**

I've changed my code and it is inserting into the database. The problem comes after the insert, because `generatedKeys` is `null`.

```
public int InsertVendor(String name, String address, String city, String province, String postalCode, String phone, String type, String email) throws SQLException {
    String strSql = "INSERT INTO Vendors (Address1,City,Province,PostalCode,Phone,VendorType,Name,Email)"
            + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet generatedKeys = null;

    int vendorno = 0;
    Connection con = null;
    //String retName ="Not Found";
    try {
        con = ds.getConnection();
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(strSql);

        stmt.setString(1, address);
        stmt.setString(2, city);
        stmt.setString(3, province);
        stmt.setString(4, postalCode);
        stmt.setString(5, phone);
        stmt.setString(6, type);
        stmt.setString(7, name);
        stmt.setString(8, email);

        int affectedRows = stmt.executeUpdate();
        if (affectedRows == 0) {
            throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no rows affected.");
        }
        generatedKeys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (generatedKeys.next()) {
            vendorno = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
        } else {
            throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no generated key obtained.");
        }


    } catch (SQLException se) {
        System.out.println("SQL issue" + se.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Other issue" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {

        if (generatedKeys != null) {
            try {
                generatedKeys.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println("SQL issue" + se.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println("SQL issue" + se.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println("SQL issue" + se.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return vendorno;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [JDBC Standards Support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jdbcvers.htm#CHDEGDHJ)

First check if your database supports returning generated keys with [DatabaseMetaData.supportsGetGeneratedKeys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#supportsGetGeneratedKeys%28%29).

Second, use one of the overloaded versions of [prepareStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to indicate that you want to retrieve generated columns:

```
// Will retrieve VendorNo
stmt = con.prepareStatement(strSql, new String[] {"VendorNo"});
```

You can also retrieve autogenerated keys with [Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS):

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement(strSql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

There is a [third](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20int%5b%5d%29) overloaded version which accepts an array of column indexes to retrieve but I deeply advice against it (retrieving by column name is safer against schema changes... better safe than sorry).

```
// Will retrieve VendorNo
stmt = con.prepareStatement(strSql, new int[] {1});
```

Also, as @Jan mentioned, take care to properly close your resources.

Comment: Hi I'm using derby db

Comment: Derby DB supports [Autogenerated keys](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/crefjavstateautogen.html) as you probably already figured out ;).

Answer (score 0):

As [seen here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), you should do your try-with-resources on the `Statement`, not on the `ResultSet`.

Comment: thank can you look at my codeI am able to insert but is null generatedKeys